# Haskell - Monad Transformers - Limit number of evaluations in an interpreter

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

I'm learning Monad Transformers and decided to write an interpreter for a simple language(with loop constructs) similar to Brainfuck using Monad Transformers. I would like to terminate the interpreter after certain number of statements.

This simple language is made of single memory cell capable of holding an Int and 5 instructions Input, Output, Increment, Decrement and Loop. A loop terminates when value in the memory is zero. Input is read from a list and similarly output is written to another list. Increment and Decrement does +1 and -1 to memory correspondingly.

I'm using `World` type to keep track of input, output (streams) and memory, `Sum Int` to count number of instructions evaluated. `Except World` to terminate evaluation after certain statements.

```
module Transformers where

import qualified Data.Map                      as Map
import           Data.Maybe
import           Control.Monad.State.Lazy
import           Control.Monad.Writer.Lazy
import           Control.Monad.Except


data Term = Input
  | Output
  | Increment
  | Decrement
  | Loop [Term]
  deriving (Show)

data World = World {
  inp :: [Int],
  out :: [Int],
  mem :: Int
} deriving Show

op_limit = 5

loop
  :: [Term]
  -> StateT World (WriterT (Sum Int) (Except World)) ()
  -> StateT World (WriterT (Sum Int) (Except World)) ()
loop terms sp = sp >> do
  s <- get
  if mem s == 0 then put s else loop terms (foldM (\_ t -> eval t) () terms)

limit :: StateT World (WriterT (Sum Int) (Except World)) ()
limit = do
  (s, count) <- listen get
  when (count >= op_limit) $ throwError s

tick :: StateT World (WriterT (Sum Int) (Except World)) ()
tick = tell 1

eval :: Term -> StateT World (WriterT (Sum Int) (Except World)) ()
eval Input =
  limit >> tick >> modify (\s -> s { inp = tail (inp s), mem = head (inp s) })
eval Output       = limit >> tick >> modify (\s -> s { out = mem s : out s })
eval Increment    = limit >> tick >> modify (\s -> s { mem = mem s + 1 })
eval Decrement    = limit >> tick >> modify (\s -> s { mem = mem s - 1 })
eval (Loop terms) = loop terms (void get)

type Instructions = [Term]

interp :: Instructions -> World -> Either World (World, Sum Int)
interp insts w =
  let sp = foldM (\_ inst -> eval inst) () insts
  in  runExcept (runWriterT (execStateT sp w))
```

Example run in ghci:

```
*Transformers> interp [Loop [Output, Decrement]]  $ World [] [] 5
Right (World {inp = [], out = [1,2,3,4,5], mem = 0},Sum {getSum = 10})
```

The monad `limit` based on count and should decide to either Fail with current state or do nothing. But I noticed that `count` in `(s, count) <- listen get` is always zero. I don't understand why is this happening. Please help me understand where I went wrong.

- Is my ordering of transformers in the stack correct? Are there any rules (informal) to decide the layering?

Comment: I only gave a quick look, but it seems that you want to read your "number of statements", which currently is modeled with a writer monad. If so, don't use the writer monad since you need to _read_. Put your counter in your world state, and remove the writer layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computations inside the `Writer` monad can't have access to their own accumulator. What's more: the accumulator is *never* forced while the computation runs, not even to WHNF. This applies to *both* the strict and lazy variants of `Writer`—the strict variant is strict in a sense unrelated to the accumulator. This unavoidable laziness in the accumulator can be a source of space leaks if the computation runs for too long.

---

Your `limit` function is not branching on the value of the "mainline" `WriterT` accumulator. The `get` action (you are using mtl) simply reads the state from the `StateT` layer, and performs no effects in the other layers: it adds `mempty` to its `WriterT` accumulator an throws no error.

Then, the `listen` extracts the `Writer` accumulator of the `get` action (only of the `get`, not of the whole computation) and adds it to the "mainline" accumulator. But this extracted value (the one returned in the tuple) will always be `mempty`, that is, `Sum 0`!

---

Instead of `WriterT`, you could put the counter in the `StateT` state, as @chi has mentioned. You could also use [`AccumT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Accum.html), which is very similar to `WriterT` but lets you inspect the accumulator (it also lets you force it to WHNF using bang patterns).

`AccumT` doesn't seem to have a corresponding mtl typeclass though, so you'll need to sprinkle a few lifts in order to use it.